# Always show language status

Tags: macos

Is there an small app to always show language status?

The ideal app changes the color/shape of cursor depending on current language.

Or it can be a float icon on top with current language.

Update: Mostly I'm working in full screen mode, usual scenario for me is type something to understand what is my current language. Always show menu bar is not so comfortable for me.

Comment: System prefs > Keyboard > Input sources > Show input menu in menu bar… puts the country flag on the menu bar.

Comment: @Tetsujin that is for the keyboard as input source.

Comment: …which changes per language… or did I miss something? (bearing in mind I only speak one language & that, badly - I'm no eggspurt in that bit of the OS ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin well I beet you on this one :) I speak 5 of which 3  almost fluently . So  I have a German keyboard Mac and set to German input keyboard in the menu bar. But my OS is set to English.

Comment: Mein Deutsch ist etwas ermm… Scheiße… Français, pire...

Answer (score 2):

You can use ShowyEdge to show indicators for current input langauges.

https://showyedge.pqrs.org/

It also works in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by enabling the keyboard shortcut.

[image: input source]

Now in full screen mode there will be a pop up when you use the keyboard shortcut (cmd+space) letting you see or change the input language.

[image: animation]

The advantage of this method is you do not have something floating on you full screen all the time, but only when you call for it.

Comment: Your answer is very close, thanks. But I'd prefer to know the current language by shape of cursor or at least by the float icon somewhere in the corner.

Comment: That is your choice, having something floating on the full screen window at all times. It would be a 3d party app then most probably.